# Error: Subquery is returning more than one value. How to fix this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is a part of my stored procedure. I am having an above mentioned error in this query

```
 from Log PA
  left join workflow WF on PA.newWFid =
 (CASE 
 WHEN PA.UserCode is not null THEN (SELECT ExistingwfID from RMShuffleLog RM 
 LEFT JOIN PackageApprovalLog PA on PA.ShuffleId = RM.ShuffleId )
 end)
```

It was working fine but I added the case expression in join condition above.
This is what I added above:

```
     left join workflow WF on PA.newWFid =
 (CASE 
 WHEN PA.UserCode is not null THEN (SELECT ExistingwfID from RMShuffleLog RM 
 LEFT JOIN PackageApprovalLog PA on PA.ShuffleId = RM.ShuffleId )
 end)
```

After this, it is showing me error.

```
      Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, 
     <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression
```

.My logic is to check if the first row of the user code is null then select existingwfid from RMshufflelog. Can anyobdy tell me what the problem is?

Comment: The error message says it all. What do you want to do when this happens?

Comment: Your `SELECT` inside `CASE` seems to be returning more than one row. Check that and fix.

Comment: @jarlh I want to have  case expression which checks if the first row of user code is not null then it selects the existingwfid from my table. How do I check for the first row?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy how to make it return one row? I want to check if the usercode of first row is not null then it executes the select statement

Comment: You should able to check that. Run that subquery separately and see how many rows are returning. Without the visibility to your data, we can't predict it. May be try adding the `where` condition in the subquery as well. `where PA.ApprovalCode = 116 AND PA.transid=2472`

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy ok Thanks. How can I check if  the usercode of the first row is not null. My query here  WHEN PA.UserCode is not null just check whether the usercode is not null but does not specify the first row.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy logid is the primary key of Packageapprovaltable. I am using Sql server

Comment: `How can I check if the usercode of the first row is not null?` _THAT_ is your actual question. What you have posted above is what you see referred to as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you are asking about one of your attempts to answer the actual question instead of asking the question. The solution is to post a new question, asking the actual question, and include related table schemas and sample data there. Tools to assist are available here: [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 1):

This query is being used as a *scalar subquery*, meaning that you get the specified error if it returns more than one row:

```
(SELECT ExistingwfID
 FROM RMShuffleLog RM LEFT JOIN
      PackageApprovalLog PA 
      ON PA.ShuffleId = RM.ShuffleId
```

)

This will occur if `RMShuffleLog` has more than one row or `PackageApprovalLog` has more than one matching row.

You have a `PA` in the outer query.  So I am guessing you want a correlated clause:

```
(SELECT ExistingwfID
 FROM RMShuffleLog RM
 WHERE PA.ShuffleId = RM.ShuffleId
)
```

This is (informed) speculation.  There could be other issues with your query as well.

Comment: I know my query is returning more than one row. But how can I fix this? What I want to achieve is I want to check if the first row of usercode is not null then my select query will be executed.